# Micro SD memory on Windows 10 computers

Tags: windows-10, micro-sd-card

In a Windows 10 laptop will extra memory as a Micro SD card typically appear as an enlarged C drive or will it appear as a different drive letter?

Answer (score 1):

In windows 10, a MicroSD card will appear as a different filesystem, so it will have its own driveletter in most cases. In some cases, it will appear as a different drive object in your explorer without actually having a letter attached to it.

It will however, never be an expansion of your C drive.